# getMapData returns NULL in R

Tags: r, leaflet, shiny

I'm trying to use the `getMapData` function inside an R shiny app, but the function returns NULL whenever I call it.

```
library(leaflet)

# works
m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-80,30,4)
m

# returns null
getMapData(m)
```

The use in Shiny is no different. To provide an example, this also doesn't work (I've included a couple other outputs to show that the `input$map_click` is working):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map"),
  verbatimTextOutput("mapdata0"),
  verbatimTextOutput("mapdata1"),
  verbatimTextOutput("mapdata2")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  counter <- reactiveValues(n=0)

  # map as output object
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% 
      addTiles() %>%
      setView(-80,35,4)
  })

  # map as leafletProxy
  m <- leafletProxy("map")

  # store map data on click -- click works, but getMapData not working
  observeEvent(input$map_click,{
    counter$n <- counter$n + 1
    output$mapdata0 <- renderPrint({print(paste0('click worked (click ',counter$n,")"))})
    output$mapdata1 <- renderPrint({getMapData(m)})
    output$mapdata2 <- renderPrint({getMapData(leafletProxy("map"))})
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can someone help me figure out what is wrong with the `getMapData` function in R?

Comment: What are you expecting to get back when you've passed no data?

Comment: According to [rdocumentation.org](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.0.2/topics/getMapData), the `getMapData` function "returns the map's data". I wrongly assumed this would include information about the map boundaries (ie, lat/lon) -- so that I could (based on user input) fix the boundaries in a 2nd leaflet map (in a different tab) to match the 1st. You and another have already answered my question _as written_. Should I accept an answer and post a new question? Thanks

Comment: Yes, I think that's a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMapData` returns the data. You've called `leaflet()` which has not defined any data.

```
> m <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-80,30,4)
> getMapData(m)
NULL
```

If you call it with some data, then you get that data back:

```
> nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
> m <- leaflet(nc) %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-80,30,4)
> getMapData(m)
Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
[etc]
```

Its not clear, but `getMapData` returns the `data` argument to the `leaflet` function:

```
Usage:

     leaflet(data = NULL, width = NULL, height = NULL, padding = 0,
       options = leafletOptions(), elementId = NULL,
       sizingPolicy = leafletSizingPolicy(padding = padding))

Arguments:

    data: a data object. Currently supported objects are matrices, data
          frames, spatial objects from the ‘sp’ package
          (‘SpatialPoints’, ‘SpatialPointsDataFrame’, ‘Polygon’,
          ‘Polygons’, ‘SpatialPolygons’, ‘SpatialPolygonsDataFrame’,
          ‘Line’, ‘Lines’, ‘SpatialLines’, and
          ‘SpatialLinesDataFrame’), and spatial data frames from the
          ‘sf’ package.
```

Answer (score 0):

The function only returns data stored in the attribute `leafletData`, as you can see in the function's [source code](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/44df7d18a2618e0aeecb4145d765e597ec65878b/R/leaflet.R#L107-L112).

You can try this in your example as well:

```
library (leaflet)
m <- leaflet () %>% addTiles () %>% setView (-80,30,4)
attributes (m$x)
# $names
# [1] "options" "calls"   "setView"
attr (m$x, "leafletData")
# NULL
```

From my understanding this means that the function works as it should, which is also confirmed (although in very little detail) in the package documentation.